# Why is my output printing out twice?

Tags: perl

I've written a script that takes a command line argument `-s`, and allows me to add a search term after it.

It then feeds that into my first function, connects to a SQL database, searches for the term, and returns the results in an array.

It then calls the second function, prints the array, and outputs a `-1` or a `0` depending on whether any results were found.

Finally it is supposed to check if the result is not equal to `0`, and if so print out that no results were found.

Everything is working but my results are printing twice. Any idea why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Getopt::Std;
use strict;

getopt('s:');
our ($opt_s);
my $search = $opt_s;

my @array = function1($search);
&function1($search);

&function2(@array);
if (&function2(@array) != 0) {
    print "No results found for '$search'", "\n";
}

sub function1 {
    my $search = $_[0];

    our $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=database", "root", "password")
        or die $DBI::errstr;

    my $sql = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
        "SELECT Player from Players_Sport where Sport like '$search'")
        or die $DBI::errstr;

    my @array = map { $_->[0] } @$sql;

    $dbh->disconnect
        or warn "Disconnection failed: $DBI::errstr\n";

    return @array;
}

sub function2 {
    my @array = @_;
    my $arrayvalue;

    print("\n", "@array", "\n");

    if (scalar(@array) == 0) {
        $arrayvalue = -1;
    }
    else {
        $arrayvalue = 0;
    }

    return $arrayvalue;
}
```

Comment: After skimming your code, looks like you call `function2` twice, in which you print there and in your `if`.

Comment: I'm still extremely new at this. So using an "if" causes it to actually run and not just evaluate the case? If so what's the best course of action to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, every time you call a function it will evaluate it. I know that seems weird.  But how about you assign a variable to the function and check that in your `if`?  Whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: You don't have to use '&' before functions when you're calling them (hasn't been necessary for years and years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `&function2(@array);` twice, which causes `"\n", "@array", "\n"` to be printed twice.  Just call the function once, store the return value in a variable, and test the variable rather than calling the function again — or, even better, in this specific instance you could just dispense with the first call entirely.